# jquery: how can i know which element has a z-index when you click on the link?

Tags: jquery, z-index, jquery-1.9, nodename

How can I find which element has a z-index when you click on the link? For instance,

html,

```
<ul class="selected">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
</ul>
```

css,

```
.selected {
    z-index:10;
}
```

If I click the link **1**, then the `ul` has the z-index.
If I click the link **3** then return `li` has it.
If I click the link **5** then return `a` has it.

Is it possible?

I suppose I will use `get(0).nodeName` to return what node name it is. But the z-index is not on the link itself but on `li` or `ul`.

jquery,

```
$("a").click(function(){

    var zindex = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);

    if(zindex) alert($(this).get(0).nodeName);

});
```

Comment: So if you click on 3, you want the li returned?

Comment: Then wouldn't this work: `$('.selected').click(function(e){
console.log(this);
});`

Comment: Maybe, but I am in the case that I don't know it has the class name of `.selected` in the document....

Comment: @j08691.. shouldn't it be `$('.selected').click(function(e){ console.log($(this).closest('li')); })`

Comment: @lauthiamkok.. If the element does not have the `selected` class then the event will not be fired in the first place

Comment: yea that's why i don't think i can use `.selected` as the starting point...

Comment: the z-index is sometime on ul.

Comment: Guess I'm unclear as to what you need then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you would have to add a position to those elements, otherwise they won't have a z-index, and would just return auto.

```
.selected {
    z-index : 10;
    position: relative;
}
```

Then you look at the element itself, and then it's parents, to see if any of them has a matching z-index, like so:

```
$("a").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var Zidx    = 10,
        closest = null;

    $(this).parents().addBack().each(function() {
        if ( parseInt( $(this).css('z-index'), 10) === Zidx) {
            closest = this;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (closest) alert( $(closest).prop('tagName') );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/37RUP/)